# Add or edit product not load when canonical enable

Tags: magento2.4, canonical

I installed the SEO module on the localhost and when it enters the products I can not edit or add the products
I noticed that activating Canonical in mageworx does not load the full screen
Interestingly, this problem is not seen in Chrome
I noticed that when Canonical is enabled in Mageworx seo, the screen does not load and the spinner does not hide
Where can the problem come from?
How can I remove Canonical from the Product Management page?

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I gave you the correct answer for the content page (CMS) to add a canonical tag. Please follow the below steps:

Go to Admin Panel > Content > Pages > Open CMS Page > Design > Layout Update XML

Add code in there:

```
<head>
      <link rel="canonical" src="www.example.com/page-url-key" src_type="url"/>
</head>
```